# Content appended with JSON and DOM problems

Tags: jquery, json, html

Hi I have an application with jQuery + HTML5 + JSON and I have the next question:

I load such a big amount of content through a JSON system and it is appended to a div called content. The thing is that JSON don't append the data to the DOM, so I have to call a function to refresh all the functions due to those new appended data is not recognised by the selectors.

What I do is to put the selectors and triggers in a function and every time I run the JSON file, I call this function but I feel this is not optimised.

- Is there any way to avoid calling this function ?
- I seen that some people use the on() method, is this a better solution for the problem?
- Will it be the same by using live()?

Thanks

Comment: Provide the sample code what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding elements to the DOM, you must call the event handlers again, because the selectors you use will come up empty.

One solution to this, is attaching the event handlers to objects that are always on the DOM, and are never removed, like the wrapper around the container div.

The `live()` method is deprecated.
`on()`is just an easier way to bind, still needs selectors that are not empty.